# How to set Map values in spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to spark-scala development. I am trying to create map values in spark using scala but getting nothing printed

```
def createMap() : Map[String, Int] = {
var tMap:Map[String, Int] = Map()
val tDF = spark.sql("select a, b, c from temp")
for (x <- tDF) {
  val k = x.getAs[Long](0) + "|" + x.getAs[Long](1)
  val v = x.getAs[Int](2)
  tMap += ( k -> v )
  println( k -> v ) ///----------This print values
}
println("Hellllooooooooo1")
for ((k,v) <- tMap) println("key = " + k+ ", value= " + v) ////------This prints nothing
println("Hellllooooooooo2")
return tMap
}
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user8598832 gives how to do it properly (for some value of properly).  The reason your approach doesn't work is that you're adding (k, v) to the map in an executor, but the println occurs in the driver, which generally won't see the map(s) in the executor(s) (to the extent that it might, that's just an artifact of running it in local mode not in a distributed mode).

Answer (score 1):

The "right" (if collecting to driver is ever right) way to do it:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

tDF.select(concat_ws("|", col("a"), col("b")), col("c")).as[(String, Int)].rdd.collectAsMap
```

Comment: Sorry, I was already able to do this alternatively. But my questions is what is wrong in the code that I posted originally? And also what is the concept behind it?